# Async in Console Application

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In this sample code the code runs in a sync way. Why the task blocks the DoIndependentWork() instead block only in the webTask.Result? I know I can use Task.Run() and something else, but I'm trying to understand the async and await a little better.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webTask = AccessTheWebAsync();
    DoIndependentWork();
    Console.WriteLine("AccessTheWebAsync result: {0}", webTask.Result);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Console.WriteLine("AccessTheWebAsync in Thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    var urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    return urlContents.Length;
}

static void DoIndependentWork()
{
    Console.WriteLine("DoIndependentWork in Thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your async method still runs on the same thread as the caller; it just returns to the caller as soon as it hits an `await` call. That is why `Thread.Sleep(5000)` still blocks the thread.

In async-await land, you should use `Task.Delay` instead:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```